# Creating default object from empty value:PHP 5.4

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am getting an error like Creating default object from empty value on line 
196($settings->{$v->Name} = $setting;
). I think, it's because I have upgraded php to 5.4 version.
So that I have set $setting =(object) null instead of $setting =null. But i couldn't correct it on line 196($settings->{$v->Name} = $setting;).

```
$settings;

 foreach($SettingsRows as $v)
      {
    $setting =(object) null;

    $setting->ID = $v->ID;
    $setting->Name = $v->Name;
    $setting->Value = $v->Value;
    $setting->Class = $v->ClassName;
    $setting->Form = new $setting->Class($setting);
    $settings->{$v->Name} = $setting;
}
```

How can I set $setting value to $settings->{$v->Name} ?
What I need to change here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks sketchy, but apparently you need `$settings = new stdClass` before the `foreach` loop. (`new stdClass` is the same thing as `(object) null`, but more clear in my opinion.)

And it really looks like `$settings` ought to just be an array (e.g., `$settings[$v->Name] = $setting;`), but I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I set $settings = new stdClass before the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me with PHP 5.4

```
$query1 = $this->db()->prepare('SELECT id,title FROM category');
    $query1->execute();

    $d['query1']=(object) null;

    foreach($query1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $k=>$v){

            $d['query1']->$k=$v;

            $query2 = $this->db()->prepare('SELECT id,title FROM page');

            $query2->execute();

            $d['query2']=(object) null;
            foreach($query2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $k=>$v){

                $d['query2']->$k=$v;

            }
    }
    return $d;
```